# Search and delete in ubuntu

Tags: linux, file, ubuntu, sed

Hi i am using ubuntu shell, i am trying to delete unique line in a file after the user has key in 2 inputs however is not deleting in the txt docs. Is there something wrong with my code? thanks. ":" is a delimiter in the txt

```
read input1
read input2

sed  "/$input1:$input2/d" sample.txt
```

Comment: please show the contents of sample.txt and sample inputs

Comment: It works fine with me. What is the content of inputs/file?

Comment: Post the contents in that file.

Comment: These are some data.
Grapes of Wrath:Blaine Blah:73.9:12:2
Book of Test:Scott Finland:20.9:20:8

Answer (score 0):

You need inplace change and you could use -i option with your command like:

```
sed  -i.bak "/$input1:$input2/d" sample.txt
```

So post your command you will get additional file:

```
sample.txt.bak - as original file
sapmple.txt with line containing your pattern deleted.
```

Comment: I am sorry still not working for me both files still contain the data.